# Spring boot google calendar api project: How to convert AngularJS front end to html and Thymeleaf front end?

Tags: java, spring-boot, frontend, google-calendar-api

https://github.com/a2cart/google-calendar-api

Above is a link to a project example that has google calendar up and running. I have implemented this code into my project however the front end of my project uses html and Thymeleaf. I don't have much experience coding so I am at a loss as to how to implement it.

Comment: angularJS is HTML mixed with javascript, how would you want to convert the javascript part to html and thymeleaf? I really don't understand what you are trying to accomplish here.

Comment: @Maurice I am trying to implement google's calendar API into my spring boot project that uses tymeleaf but i have no idea how to do that. In that link it says "The samples are all single-page apps using Spring Boot and Spring OAuth on the back end. They also all use AngularJS on the front end, but the changes needed to convert to a different JavaScript framework or to use server side rendering would be minimal."

Comment: `but the changes needed to convert to a different JavaScript framework or to use server side rendering would be minimal` this part basically means that you should get out all the AngularJs stuff (thats what is making it a single page app) and replace it with your own frontend, (HTML and Thymeleaf)

Comment: @Maurice I know that, my question is how do I do that. I don't know what my html code should be

Comment: maybe this helps: https://nixmash.com/post/using-google-maps-api-with-thymeleaf-and-spring Its about implementing google maps api with thymeleaf and spring. Implementing the calendar api should follow the same principles.

Comment: @Maurice  Thank you so much for that link I will give it a go!  I really appreciate your help